# Rails Form Submittal Error NOT NULL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise

So I'm building a devise user registration form for my rails app and I added a column to the users table for 'type,' with the goal of having two different types of users.  Type is assigned as an integer in the Users table.  When the form is submitted, I get an error.  Not sure why.  When I submit the form, I enter a '1' for the type just to see if it works and it doesn't take.

Here's the error.

```
SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: users.type: 
INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at", 
"confirmation_token", "confirmation_sent_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

and here's the form code.

```
<h2>Project Creator Registration</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>

<div class="form-group" align="left">
  <%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, required: true, class: "form-control" %>
</div>

<div class="form-group" align="left">
  <%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, required: true, class: "form-control" %>
</div>

<div class="form-group" align="left">
  <%= f.label :type %><br />
  <%= f.number_field :type, autofocus: true, required: true, class: "form-control" %>
</div>

<div class="field" align="left">
  <%= f.label :password %>
  <% if @minimum_password_length %>
  <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
  <% end %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password, required: true, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control"  %>
</div>

<div class="field" align="left">
  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, required: true, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control" %>
</div></br>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>
</div>

<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Any suggestions???

Comment: `type` is a reserved column by default for STI in rails. Change the column name and try.

Comment: Or [disable](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/102961#1138176) STI using other column.

Comment: Thanks, @ArupRakshit!

Comment: Include your own answer to help others :D